# Jumping Issue When 'invalid-feedback' Displayed For Bootstrap 4 Input

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an `input` with an add-on which i have created a custom `focus` as i wanted the '%' add-on at the end of the field to also focus when i click in the field. All this is working fine but i have noticed a niggle where when the error is displayed when you click in/out the `input` is causes jumping.

I have created a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/murday1983/yswgx17t/8/)

I know the issue is with the `height` in the `.input-group:focus-within` `CSS` as if i remove it it stops but then the issue i then have is that if you remove the `height` when the error is displayed, the blue `focus` box is displayed around the error message also which i don't want.

Please view my fiddle for all code and remove the `height` to see what i mean when i mention the issue i have without it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rearrange your layout. Place the error outside of the `input-group` and show/hide it in respect to the input validation.

There is til some jumping, and it is because bootstrap adds and remove box-shadow and border from the input.

https://jsfiddle.net/jsrm1o0x/2/